# Not Recognizing event on TouchListener Cocos2d-JS

Tags: cocos2d-js

I have a touch listener

```
var touchListener = cc.EventListener.create({
    event: cc.EventListener.MOUSE,
    onMouseDown: function (event) { 
        console.log("working");
        console.log(event._y);
    }
});
```

When I click the screen the "working" message shows, but then I get js_console_log : Error processing arguments for the event._y

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to get the event's Y axis coordinate is: `event.getLocationY()`.
If you put a breakpoint in `console.log("working");` you could inspect the `event` object and see all it's methods and properties :)